# Ubuntu 14.04 Google earth 64 starts initial screen appears then quits

Tags: google-earth

I have tried everything listed on this site. Hers is my crash log:

```
Major Version 7
Minor Version 1
Build Number 0004
Build Date Mar 30 2015
Build Time 22:42:31
OS Type 3
OS Major Version 3
OS Minor Version 13
OS Build Version 0
OS Patch Version 0
Crash Signal 11
Crash Time 1462077456
Up Time 1.84002

Stacktrace from glibc:
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x23924c)[0x7fdeb75e424c]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x2394ad)[0x7fdeb75e44ad]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10340)[0x7fdeb82b1340]
./libbase.so(_ZN5earth15GfxCardInfoUnix25GetGraphicsCardMemoryInMBERi+0xe)[0x7fdeb186754e]
/opt/google/earth/free/libevll.so(_ZN5earth4evll13VisualContext26DetectHardwareCapabilitiesEv+0x450)[0x7fdea568b250]
/opt/google/earth/free/libevll.so(_ZN5earth4evll13VisualContext11OpenContextEN3Gap3Gfx25igRenderDestinationFormatERKNS0_8InitInfoE+0x1f4)[0x7fdea568b694]
/opt/google/earth/free/libevll.so(_ZN5earth4evll13VisualContext4initERKNS0_8InitInfoE+0x123)[0x7fdea568b7f3]
/opt/google/earth/free/libevll.so(_ZN5earth4evll17RenderContextImpl4initERKNS0_8InitInfoE+0xeb)[0x7fdea5538b9b]
./librender.so(_ZN12RenderWidget6SetApiEPN5earth4evll3APIE+0x7a)[0x7fdeaed6a64a]
./librender.so(_ZN5earth6render12RenderWindow12createWidgetEv+0x17c)[0x7fdeaed5912c]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN5earth6client12ModuleWidget9showEventEP10QShowEvent+0x86)[0x7fdeb75c4956]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget5eventEP6QEvent+0x599)[0x7fdeb66eb299]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0xac)[0x7fdeb669449c]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x20f)[0x7fdeb669c73f]
./libQtCore.so.4(_ZN16QCoreApplication14notifyInternalEP7QObjectP6QEvent+0x8c)[0x7fdeb49dda6c]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x12a)[0x7fdeb66ed2ca]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0xb1)[0x7fdeb66ed0e1]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7fdeb66ed1df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7fdeb66ed5da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x146)[0x7fdeb66ed176]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7fdeb66ed1df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0xb1)[0x7fdeb66ed0e1]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7fdeb66ed1df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7fdeb66ed5da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x146)[0x7fdeb66ed176]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7fdeb66ed1df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0xb1)[0x7fdeb66ed0e1]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7fdeb66ed1df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7fdeb66ed5da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x146)[0x7fdeb66ed176]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7fdeb66ed1df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7fdeb66ed5da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x146)[0x7fdeb66ed176]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7fdeb66ed1df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7fdeb66ed5da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate12showChildrenEb+0x146)[0x7fdeb66ed176]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN14QWidgetPrivate11show_helperEv+0x3f)[0x7fdeb66ed1df]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10setVisibleEb+0x1aa)[0x7fdeb66ed5da]
./libQtGui.so.4(_ZN7QWidget10showNormalEv+0x3d)[0x7fdeb66dec0d]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN10MainWindow18readScreensizeInfoEv+0xbc5)[0x7fdeb75c11c5]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN5earth6client11Application12SetupMainWinENS0_3Kvw7ProductEb+0x323)[0x7fdeb766d783]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(_ZN5earth6client11Application3runEv+0x700)[0x7fdeb7674250]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(+0x238c62)[0x7fdeb75e3c62]
./libgoogleearth_free.so(earthmain+0x1dc)[0x7fdeb75e3e6c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7fdeb7bf7ec5]
./googleearth-bin[0x4008a9]
```

Comment: I don't believe you have "tried everything". Specifically what have you tried?

Comment: I initially installed the resent deb package, Then the application would run for a moment and shut down,  reinstalled G. earth same problem. 
I was using a HP all in one machine with A8 processor. I switched to a HP laptop with A 8 processor. 
Installed all libraries and installed G. Earth. Same problem, 
Then deactivation of network and this Google ran, and then reactivating network access. G. Earth ran fine.
I'll try The same for  other Hp I sincerely thank everyone for their time responding to my request.

Comment: So, you have tried maybe 5 things, times 2 machines. A paltry subset  of "everything". A proper description of what you have done, (cut-and-paste commands and output, properly formatted) would give  people tryi

Comment: -ing to help you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the flawed installation with:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove google-earth*
```

Then install it again.  You appear to be running the current deb version, so you can try first with the version that you installed before.  If that fails try a fresh download from Google.

Comment: Did that on the All In One Hp, now he ole laptop with AMD A8 processor. G Earth will run if network operations are disabled. After it starts I can re enable Network functionality and it runs just fine.  

The darn ALLINOne just gives me the initial G Earth start screen and stops.
I have installed every Library file mentioned and your suggestions. Which I appreciate it.

The AlInOne is in prenuptial storage while I move.